# Is there a way to register a data asset in Azure Data Catalog via api without user-login?

Tags: rest, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-data-catalog

My app gets a token and can make api calls to the ADC like searching. But the request for registration of new asset fails, because the field "LastRegisterdBy" must not be null/empty and has to correspond to current user.
However the token does not contain any user information (AccessToken().Result.UserInfo.DisplayableId is null).

I mostly followed the get started get-started project MS provides (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/data-catalog-dotnet-get-started/blob/master/Program.cs)

But i use

`AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientCredential).ConfigureAwait(false)`

instead of

`AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always))`.

This so nobody has to enter his credentials. The goal is to run the code in ssis package, which will execute on a weekly basis to catch any updates in the data automatically.

This is the outline of my code:

```cs
    class Program
        {
            static string clientIDFromAzureAppRegistration = "";
            static string clientSecret = "";
            static AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
            static string catalogName = "catalog";
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var authResult = AccessToken();
                string upn = authResult.Result.UserInfo.DisplayableId;
                var id = RegisterDataAsset(authResult, SampleJson("test", upn));
            }
                static async Task<AuthenticationResult> AccessToken()
        {
            if (authResult == null)
            {
                //Resource Uri for Data Catalog API
                string resourceUri = "https://api.azuredatacatalog.com";

                //To learn how to register a client app and get a Client ID, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt403303.aspx#clientID   
                string clientId = clientIDFromAzureAppRegistration;
                string clientS = clientSecret;

                // Create an instance of AuthenticationContext to acquire an Azure access token

                var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/52497ec2-0945-4f55-8021-79766363dd96";
                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
                var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientS);

                // Call AcquireToken to get an Azure token from Azure Active Directory token issuance endpoint
                //  AcquireToken takes a Client Id that Azure AD creates when you register your client app.
                authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientCredential).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            return authResult;
        }

     static string RegisterDataAsset(Task<AuthenticationResult> authResult, string json){
    ...
    }
    static HttpWebResponse SetRequestAndGetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, Task<AuthenticationResult> authResult, string payload = null){
    ...
    }
    static string SampleJson(string name, string upn){
    ...}
```

With upn = authResult.Result.UserInfo.DisplayableId; i get:

{"error":{"code":"InvalidPropertyValue","message":"Invalid input value for one of the properties. Path: 'properties.lastRegisteredBy.upn'. Details: Value cannot be null, empty or consists entirely of whitespaces."}}

Wit upn = "test@user":

{"error":{"code":"InvalidLastRegisteredBy","message":"LastRegisteredBy is different from the current user."}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, its quite simple:

The user-name of the app is: clientIDFromAzureAppRegistration + "@" + tenantId.